# Java base as Template parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am semi Java literate and trying something in Groovy.

Is the following possible in Groovy/Java:

```
public class A {
}
public class B {
}

public class C<Ta extends A, Tb extends B> extends Ta {
   public Ta[] bArray;
   public Tb[] getAllBs()
   {
      Tb[] ret = new Tb[0];
      ....
      return ret;
   }
}
```

Above definitions dont show any errors. But when I try to use C as base class for another type, I get an error:

```
public class DummyA extends A {};
public class DummyB extends B {};

public class D extends C<DummyA, DummyB> {
}
```

Above definition shows the error 'The hierarchy of the type D is inconsistent'.

If I redefine C as any of the following, the error goes away:

```
//remove the base class, Ta, from C
public class C<Ta extends A, Tb extends B> {
....
}
```

(or)

```
//Use the class A, instead of generic type Ta, as base class
public class C<Ta extends A, Tb extends B> extends A {
....
}
```

I must be breaking some Java rules, but unable to identify

Comment: For me it is failing on `Tb[] ret = new Tb[0];` with message `Cannot create a generic array of Tb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible because the superclass of the superclass of D is "generic".
And generic supertyps are not allowed! This is allowed:

```
public class C<B extends WhatElse> extends ArrayList<B>{
```

Because the superclass is clearly in the package java.lang and you only give the Superclass your "own" generic parameter.
And java needs a clear structure compiling the classes!
So example: Which methods you should be able to overwrite?

Answer (score 0):

And some information this line : `Tb[] ret = new Tb[0];` will NEVER work!
You cannot generate Generic Arrays you cannot use `new Tb();` too!